# MySql error 1054 when trying to inserts txt files into MySql

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I have multiple txt files in a directory and I want to insert all of them into mysql; the content of each file show should occupy a row. 
In MySQL, I have 2 columns: ID (auto increment), and LastName(nvarchar(45)).
However, when I run the following code, I get an error (1054). What am I doing wrong here?

```
import MySQLdb
import sys
import os
result = os.listdir("path")
path="dir_path";
for x in result:
    db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","password","myblog")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    file = open(path+x, 'r')
    file_content = file.readline()   
    file.close() 
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO clamp_test VALUES(default,file_content)')  
    db.commit()
    db.close()
```

Comment: Try INSERT INTO clamp_test (LastName) VALUES(file_content), so that you let the auto increment column do its thing. Incidentally I had to look the error code up (Unknown column in 'Field List') - please provide the detail if possible. I suspect the 'default' is what's causing the problem, though I do not know Python so may well be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables aren't expanded inside strings, you need to use a prepared statement with the variable as a parameter.

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO clamp_test VALUES(default,%s)', (file_content,))
```